# <img> tag showing image on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: html, image, mobile, localhost

I am developing simple html page(try.html) with code as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Table</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="OuterTable" align="center" cellspacing="0">
            <tr align = "center">
                <td>Your Father</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align = "center">
                <td>
                  <img src="arrow.jpg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align = "center">
                <td>You</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have placed both try.html and arrow.jpg in same folder. When opened webpage on desktop, images are displayed properly. When transferred the html page and image to mobile in same folder in internal storage, images are not getting displayed.

Please let me know, if I should specify different path for mobile page.

Edit:

Is it something wrong with the way I am testing? I am directly taking html page on mobile and opening it in chrome. Do I need to set up localhost and access through mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Change the file extension to jpeg. File information below confirms its actually a jpeg.

Comment: Tried with jpeg extension as well but still image not getting displayed on mobile browser, though it is displayed on desktop.